# What i am doing wrong in table with divs

Tags: html, css

What i am doing wrong with this table constructed with divs?
Why header row and cell row don't have the same width?

Another problem is, when resizing browser window header an cell losing their justify. I'd like to have the same movement for both header and cells. 
if you resize your browser window you will see borders moving different.

here is my code

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(31, 30, 30, 1);
}
.records {
  width: 99%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.header-cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #3a3a3a;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #494949;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.row1 {
  padding-top: 4px;
}

/* scrollbars */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(204, 51, 0, .9);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
}
/* scrollbars */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: rgba(204, 51, 0, .9);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
}
```

```html
<div class="records">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-cell">#</div>
    <div class="header-cell">Movie</div>
    <div class="header-cell">Distributor</div>
    <div class="header-cell">Country</div>
    <div class="header-cell">Language</div>
    <div class="header-cell">Name</div>       
    <div class="header-cell">Role</div>  
    <div class="header-cell">Born</div>      
    <div class="header-cell">Star Sign</div>
    <div class="header-cell">Episodes</div> 
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top:19px;">
    <div class="cell">145</div>
    <div class="cell">Game Of Thrones</div>
    <div class="cell">HBO</div>
    <div class="cell">USA</div>    
    <div class="cell">English</div>
    <div class="cell">
      <a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0227759/?ref_=tt_cl_t1">Peter Dinklage</a>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">Tyrion Lannister</div>
    <div class="cell">June 11, 1969</div>       
    <div class="cell">Gemini</div>  
    <div class="cell">2-3-4-6-11</div>  
  </div>  
  <div style="padding-top:1px;">
    <div class="cell">146</div>
    <div class="cell">Game Of Thrones</div>
    <div class="cell">HBO</div>
    <div class="cell">USA</div>    
    <div class="cell">English</div>
    <div class="cell">
      <a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3229685/?ref_=tt_cl_t4">Kit Harington</a>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">Jon Snow</div>
    <div class="cell">December 26, 1986</div>       
    <div class="cell">Capricorn</div>  
    <div class="cell">1-2-3-6-9</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for experimend here is my fiddle too https://jsfiddle.net/snart1/5Ldv5m1a/

Comment: You should use <table> tag for tables. Why are you trying use divs?

Comment: If its tabular data, why not just use a table? It will all align nicely then and semantically make more sense. Plus it will be better for accessibility.

Comment: i want to do some jquery effects on divs later...

Comment: Then put SPAN elements inside the table cells *if you absolutely have to*, but tables are the way to produce tabular data. What are you planning to do to these DIV's that you cannot do to a table cell?

Comment: If you are using javascript too you really should look at http://datatables.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your html and styles, The width of the entries row and the float: left; used instead of display: inline-block;

**HTML**

```
<div class="records" >
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-cell">#</div>
        <div class="header-cell">Movie</div>
        <div class="header-cell">Distributor</div>
        <div class="header-cell">Country</div>
        <div class="header-cell">Language</div>
        <div class="header-cell">Name</div>       
        <div class="header-cell">Role</div>  
        <div class="header-cell">Born</div>      
        <div class="header-cell">Star Sign</div>
        <div class="header-cell">Episodes</div> 
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top:19px;width:100%">
        <div class="cell">145</div>
        <div class="cell">Game Of Thrones</div>
        <div class="cell">HBO</div>
        <div class="cell">USA</div>    
        <div class="cell">English</div>
        <div class="cell"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0227759/?ref_=tt_cl_t1">Peter Dinklage</a></div>
        <div class="cell">Tyrion Lannister</div>
        <div class="cell">June 11, 1969</div>       
        <div class="cell">Gemini</div>  
        <div class="cell">2-3-4-6-11</div>  
    </div>  
    <div style="padding-top:1px;width:100%">
        <div class="cell">146</div>
        <div class="cell">Game Of Thrones</div>
        <div class="cell">HBO</div>
        <div class="cell">USA</div>    
        <div class="cell">English</div>
        <div class="cell"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3229685/?ref_=tt_cl_t4">Kit Harington</a></div>
        <div class="cell">Jon Snow</div>
        <div class="cell">December 26, 1986</div>       
        <div class="cell">Capricorn</div>  
        <div class="cell">1-2-3-6-9</div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**Style**

```
html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:95vh;
    background-color: rgba(31,30,30,1);
    overflow:hidden;
}
.records {
    width:99%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
.header-cell {
    height: 20px;
    width: 9%;
    background: #3a3a3a;
    color: #ffffff;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* margin-left: -4px; */
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    /* margin-top: 2px; */
    float: left;
}
.cell {    
    height: 20px;
    width: 9%;
    background: #cccccc;
    color: #494949;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* margin-left: -4px; */
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    /* margin-top: 2px; */
}
.header {
    /*position:fixed; */
    width:100%;
}
.row1 {
    padding-top:4px;
}

/* scrollbars */
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px;}   
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;}    
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {-webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; background: rgba(204,51,0,0.9); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); }
/* scrollbars */
::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px;}   
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;}    
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {-webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; background: rgba(204,51,0,0.9); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); }
```

Refer the update fiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/5Ldv5m1a/3/

Comment: hello Karthik..
i just update your fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/snart1/5Ldv5m1a/10/) with position fixed in header

As you see...
Header is just a little bit longer than data.. and when resizing display window it looses justification with data...
That's what i want to achieve 
same width on header and every row beneath, fixed header and when resizing header and data not to loose their justify

Comment: Hello again.. karthik
after some experiments thats what i wanted..
https://jsfiddle.net/snart1/5Ldv5m1a/13/

added 1% on rows (101% now ) and header have the same width with data!!
Now Resizing works perfect with your approach!!!

Well done man!

Thanks everyone too for his advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a highly unconventional way of making a table. HTML has the `<table>` element where tables have `<tr>` (table row) elements and `<td>` (table cell) elements. The layout would look like this:

```
<table class="tabName">
 <tr class="header">
  <td>Element1</td>
  <td>Element2</td>
  <td>Element3</td>
  <td>Element4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Element1</td>
  <td>Element2</td>
  <td>Element3</td>
  <td>Element4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Element1</td>
  <td>Element2</td>
  <td>Element3</td>
  <td>Element4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This will create 2 rows with 4 elements in each row excluding the header. Using the class name for the first table row, you can set special CSS specs on the header and other rules for the non-headers. If you want CSS rules for just the header use this:

```
.header td{
/*header styles*/
}
```

If you want to style the cells that are not part of the header use this CSS rule:

```
td:not(.header td){
/*non-header cell styles*/
}
```

For future reference, keep in mind that divs are only used to "package" a set of elements together when they share a common set of rules. So avoid rewriting the same rules for multiple elements by using the same class names for both or grouping them within a div. For example, if you have Ok and Cancel buttons together, you would put them inside a div because they will use exact same CSS rules except for the button color.

Comment: Nice answer btrballin.. but what if i'd like to have some jquery transitions? 
Could use it on td' s?

Comment: and watch the fixed header when use fixed position for header it mess everything...

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what JQuery transitions you are referring to? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i tried with table too..
rows loose radius, shadow and every other style ..
It just display only the hover..
I cant include a fiddle because, i decided not to use tables and code deleted... :(

Comment: You can have rounded corners but I would assume you need to make the grid lines match the background color so they appear like they are invisible.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```css
 .records { 
              display: table;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              overflow-y: auto;
              width: 100%;
}
.btlrow {
    display: table-row;
}
 
.cell {
    background: #cccccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #494949;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
 
 
 /* scrollbars */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px;} 
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;} 
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {-webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; background: rgba(204,51,0,0.9); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); }
 /* scrollbars */
 ::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px;} 
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;} 
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {-webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; background: rgba(204,51,0,0.9); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); }
```

```html
<div class="records" >
  <div class="btlrow">
      <div class="cell">#</div>
      <div class="cell">Movie</div>
      <div class="cell">Distributor</div>
      <div class="cell">Country</div>
      <div class="cell">Language</div>
      <div class="cell">Name</div>       
      <div class="cell">Role</div>  
      <div class="cell">Born</div>      
      <div class="cell">Star Sign</div>
      <div class="cell">Episodes</div> 
  </div>
  <div  class="btlrow">
      <div class="cell">145</div>
      <div class="cell">Game Of Thrones</div>
      <div class="cell">HBO</div>
      <div class="cell">USA</div>    
      <div class="cell">English</div>
      <div class="cell"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0227759/?ref_=tt_cl_t1">Peter Dinklage</a></div>
      <div class="cell">Tyrion Lannister</div>
      <div class="cell">June 11, 1969</div>       
      <div class="cell">Gemini</div>  
      <div class="cell">2-3-4-6-11</div>  
  </div>  
  <div class="btlrow">
      <div class="cell">146</div>
      <div class="cell">Game Of Thrones</div>
      <div class="cell">HBO</div>
      <div class="cell">USA</div>    
      <div class="cell">English</div>
      <div class="cell"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3229685/?ref_=tt_cl_t4">Kit Harington</a></div>
      <div class="cell">Jon Snow</div>
      <div class="cell">December 26, 1986</div>       
      <div class="cell">Capricorn</div>  
      <div class="cell">1-2-3-6-9</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well...
changed this line .btlrow {display: table-row;} 
to 
.btlheader {display: table-row; position:fixed;}
.btlrow {display: table-row;} 

Everything works well !!
Thanks you very much for your answer..

Comment: found a solution for your problem ,hope this will help ....here is the link (https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code need few changes in the CSS file and few CSS changes in HTML file. Below are the changes.

HTML:

```
<div class="records" >
  <div class="header">
      <div class="header-cell">#</div>
      <div class="header-cell">Movie</div>
      <div class="header-cell">Distributor</div>
      <div class="header-cell">Country</div>
      <div class="header-cell">Language</div>
      <div class="header-cell">Name</div>       
      <div class="header-cell">Role</div>  
      <div class="header-cell">Born</div>      
      <div class="header-cell">Star Sign</div>
      <div class="header-cell">Episodes</div> 
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top:19px;display: table-row;">
      <div class="cell">145</div>
      <div class="cell">Game Of Thrones</div>
      <div class="cell">HBO</div>
      <div class="cell">USA</div>    
      <div class="cell">English</div>
      <div class="cell"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0227759/?ref_=tt_cl_t1">Peter Dinklage</a></div>
      <div class="cell">Tyrion Lannister</div>
      <div class="cell">June 11, 1969</div>       
      <div class="cell">Gemini</div>  
      <div class="cell">2-3-4-6-11</div>  
  </div>  
  <div style="padding-top:1px;display: table-row;">
      <div class="cell">146</div>
      <div class="cell">Game Of Thrones</div>
      <div class="cell">HBO</div>
      <div class="cell">USA</div>    
      <div class="cell">English</div>
      <div class="cell"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3229685/?ref_=tt_cl_t4">Kit Harington</a></div>
      <div class="cell">Jon Snow</div>
      <div class="cell">December 26, 1986</div>       
      <div class="cell">Capricorn</div>  
      <div class="cell">1-2-3-6-9</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body       {width:100%;height:95vh;background-color: rgba(31,30,30,1); overflow:hidden;}
    .records        {width:99%; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; display: table}
    .header-cell    {background:#3a3a3a;color:#ffffff;display:table-cell;border:1px solid #fff;}
    .cell {background:#cccccc;color:#494949;display:table-cell;border:1px solid #fff;}
    .header         {display: table-row;}
    .row1           {padding-top:4px;}

    /* scrollbars */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px;}   
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;}    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {-webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; background: rgba(204,51,0,0.9); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); }
    /* scrollbars */
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 5px;}   
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;}    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {-webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; background: rgba(204,51,0,0.9); -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); }
```